# Install package in ubuntu obsolete release

Tags: 9.10, temperature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software on an old now unsupported Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-on-an-old-now-unsupported-ubuntu-version)

I need to install the lm-sensors package into an Ubuntu 9.10 release. I cannot update ubuntu (don't want to bother you now with the details).

It's useless to try with apt-get, so I would like to download the deb package and try it "manually".

Does anybody now where to find it?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible dupliate of http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/35775